# SwiftUI Scrollview contents are outside scrollable area

Tags: view, swiftui, scrollview, frame

I'm having trouble keeping the contents of a ScrollView contained within the scrollview:
[image]

Initially, I want to display letters A and B in the ScrollView and have the user scroll to see additional letters.  However, even though I've constrained the parent VStack to a frame with height of 120, you can also see the letter C which is outside of the ScrollView (as indicated by the blue background).  Here's the code:

```
var body: some View {            
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
         HStack(alignment: .center , spacing: 5) {
             Text("Letter").font(.tableHeader).frame(width: 75, height: 30, alignment: .center)
         } // HStack
         .frame(width: 195, height: 50, alignment: .center)
         .background(Color.green)

         VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
             GeometryReader { outsideProxy in
                 ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                     ZStack(alignment: .top) {           
                         GeometryReader { insideProxy in
                             Color.clear
                             // get offset
                         } // GeometryReader inside
                         VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                                 Text("A").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                             }
                             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                                 Text("B").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                             }
                             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                                 Text("C").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                             }
                             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                                 Text("D").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                             }
                         } // VStack
                     } // ZStack
                 } // Scrollview
             } // GeometryReader outside
             .background(Color.blue)
         } // VStack
         .frame(width: 195, height: 120, alignment: .leading)
     } // VStack
 }
```

The full code requires that use of GeometryReader (and consequently, the ZStack) which is why I've left those items in the sample above.

What is the best way to solve this issue?  Open to any improvements for coding the above layout.   Keep in mind that ultimately, I want to the user to be able to click on A, B, C, or D to be taken to the next view in the navigation stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it clipped

```
 ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
     ZStack(alignment: .top) {           
         GeometryReader { insideProxy in
             Color.clear
             // get offset
         } // GeometryReader inside
         VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                 Text("A").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
             }
             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                 Text("B").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
             }
             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                 Text("C").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
             }
             HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                 Text("D").font(.tableData).frame(width: 75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
             }
         } // VStack
     } // ZStack
 } // Scrollview
 .clipped()           // << here !!
```

Comment: OMG... wish I had posted this question 24 hours earlier... wasted so much time.  Thanks, @Asperi!

Comment: Your solution, @Asperi, fixed the main issue in the question but after adding `.clipped()` I'm noticing that the scrollview won't display the letter "D".  After reaching the bottom, the scrollview will bounce up slightly and hide the "D".  How can I get the scrollview to reach the bottom?

Comment: Very strange... I just updated to Xcode Version 12.0 (12A7209) and it looks like the original code worked fine without having to use .clipped() and all options are displayed properly.  Just sharing for those who come across this question in the future.